# Changes in an object's attribute is not permanent in main class?

Tags: java, class, oop, object

So, in my main class, I was trying to call this method from another class.

```
void Attack(String attackerName, String defenderName, double attackerDmg, double defenderHp){
    System.out.println(attackerName + " attacked " + defenderName + " causing " + attackerDmg +  " damage.");
    defenderHp -= attackerDmg;
    System.out.println(defenderName + " now has " + defenderHp + " HP.");
}
```

But I realized that the object's HP does not permanently decrease when attacked. If I was coding in C, I would be able to use pointers to solve such problem but in java I do not have a solution. The method above is in the same class as the object's specifications are in.

Thanks!

EDIT: The classes I was talking about are:

```
public class Heroes {

private String name;
private int hp;
private int mana;
private int armor;
private int attack;
private int strength;
private int agility;
private int intelligence;

public Heroes(String name, int hp, int mana, int armor, int attack, int strength, int agility, int intelligence) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hp = hp;
    this.mana = mana;
    this.armor = armor;
    this.attack = attack;
    this.strength = strength;
    this.agility = agility;
    this.intelligence = intelligence;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getHp() {
    return hp;
}

public int getMana() {
    return mana;
}

public int getArmor() {
    return armor;
}

public int getAttack() {
    return attack;
}

public int getStrength() {
    return strength;
}

public int getAgility() {
    return agility;
}

public int getIntelligence() {
    return intelligence;
}
```

}

```
public class Juggernaut extends Heroes {

private boolean skill1;
private boolean skill2;
private boolean skill3;
private boolean skill4;

public Juggernaut(int hp, int mana, int armor, int attack, int strength, int agility, int intelligence, boolean skill1, boolean skill2, boolean skill3, boolean skill4) {
    super("Juggernaut", hp, mana, armor, attack, strength, agility, intelligence);
    this.skill1 = skill1;
    this.skill2 = skill2;
    this.skill3 = skill3;
    this.skill4 = skill4;
}

double currentHp(){
    return getHp() + (10 * getArmor()) + (2.5 * getStrength());
}
double currentMana(){
    return getMana() + (2.5 * getIntelligence());
}
double currentDmg(){
    return getAttack() + (1.0 * getAgility());
}

void Attack(String attackerName, String defenderName, double attackerDmg, double defenderHp){
    System.out.println(attackerName + " attacked " + defenderName + " causing " + attackerDmg +  " damage.");
    defenderHp -= attackerDmg;
    System.out.println(defenderName + " now has " + defenderHp + " HP.");
}


public boolean getSkill1() {
    return skill1;
}

public boolean getSkill2() {
    return skill2;
}

public boolean getSkill3() {
    return skill3;
}

public boolean getSkill4() {
    return skill4;
}
```

}

```
public class Pudge extends Heroes {

private boolean skill1;
private boolean skill2;
private boolean skill3;
private boolean skill4;

public Pudge(int hp, int mana, int armor, int attack, int strength, int agility, int intelligence, boolean skill1, boolean skill2, boolean skill3, boolean skill4) {
    super("Pudge", hp, mana, armor, attack, strength, agility, intelligence);
    this.skill1 = skill1;
    this.skill2 = skill2;
    this.skill3 = skill3;
    this.skill4 = skill4;
}

double currentHp(){
    return getHp() + (10 * getArmor()) + (2.5 * getStrength());
}
double currentMana(){
    return getMana() + (2.5 * getIntelligence());
}
double currentDmg() {
    return getAttack() + (1.0 * getAgility());
}

void Attack(String attackerName, String defenderName, double attackerDmg, double defenderHp){
    System.out.println(attackerName + " attacked " + defenderName + " causing " + attackerDmg +  " damage.");
    defenderHp -= attackerDmg;
    System.out.println(defenderName + " now has " + defenderHp + " HP.");


}





public boolean getSkill1() {
    return skill1;
}

public boolean getSkill2() {
    return skill2;
}

public boolean getSkill3() {
    return skill3;
}

public boolean getSkill4() {
    return skill4;
}
```

}

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Juggernaut juggernaut = new Juggernaut(200,75,0,26,20,26,14,true,true,true,true);
    Pudge pudge = new Pudge(200,75, -1,33,25,14,14,true,true,true,true);

    juggernaut.Attack(juggernaut.getName(),pudge.getName(),juggernaut.currentDmg(), pudge.currentHp());
    pudge.Attack(pudge.getName(), juggernaut.getName(), pudge.currentDmg(),juggernaut.currentHp());



}
```

}

Comment: Please show your whole code and the classes you are using.

Comment: @alejandrogiron alright

Comment: You have changed your method's parameter defenderHP. If you want to change class attribute (and you have it defined in your class), you should address it like this.defenderHP in the method (when you change it).

Comment: @NataljaOlefire So then any changes made in this.defenderHP would make change in juggernaut.getcurrentHp()?

Comment: What is this : `this.skill1 = skill1;`?

Comment: @Blasanka they were for my future methods I was going to create. Ignore them

Comment: No, with your current implementation not really, @Huzo. Your class attributes in the parent class are private - so they are not directly visible in a child class. You can create a setter method in a parent and use it (instead of this.defenderHP use setDefenderHP(defenderHP) - it will set the attribute for you). And then - yes, your getter should return the correct result.

Comment: Very comprehensive now. @NataljaOlefire Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that you are decreasing the value of the variable `defenderHP` you are passing (a parameter), and not the actual object's value. When the method finishes executing, `defenderHP` goes out of scope and gets destroyed. A possible solution for this problem is having get and set method for the variables in your class. If you have:

```
//In your Hero class
public void reduceHp(int damage)
{
    this.hp= hp - damage;
}
```

Now, you modify the `Attack` methods by passing two objects, instead of each one of the values needed:

```
public void Attack(Hero attacker, Hero defender)
{
    //decrease the defender's HP by the attacker's attack
    defender.reduceHP(attacker.getAttack());

    //Print out names and damaged caused
    System.out.println(attacker.getName() + " has attacked " + defender.getName() + " causing " + attacker.getAttack());


    System.out.println(defender.getName() + " now has " + defender.getHP());
}
```

Comment: I see. I had not typed setters since I have a constructor. Normally wouldnt it be redundant to have both setters and a constructor?

Comment: Not redundant. The constructor is responsible for setting the initial values of an object when you create it. Then, the setters can change the values of that object's variables later on if you need to. It's either writing setters or declaring public variables, depending on your needs.

Comment: This is not a setter.  This is a mutator.  And it is evil to give a mutator a name which makes it look like a setter.

Comment: Hi @MikeNakis I'm not aware of the difference, would you care to explain?

Comment: `setHP()` does not set the hp.  It modifies the existing hp.  When any programmer sees `object.setHP( 10 )` they expect that object.HP will be exactly 10 afterwards.

Comment: @MikeNakis Thank you for pointing that out, I've changed the name.

Answer (score 2):

In java instead of passing a `double` you would pass an object containing a `double`, so that you can modify the `double`.

Better yet, you would structure your code differently, so that both the `double` and the function that operates on it belong to the same class, so that you do not have to pass the `double` as a parameter to the function; instead, the function would modify the `double` via `this`.

**EDIT**

```
class MyObjectWhichCanBeAttacked
{
    private double healthPoints;

    void applyAttack( double healthPointsToSubtract )
    {
        this.healthPoints -= healthPointsToSubtract;
    }
}
```

Comment: so, using this.defenderHp would point at whatever I type in method instead of double defenderHp ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Double values do not point to anything.

Comment: I probably misunderstood your answer. I would be grateful if you can give a quick demonstration of what you meant.

Comment: there you go, I amended my answer.

Comment: Oh now I get it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You must understand about variable scope. There are three type of variables,

> **Local Variables:**
>
> - When you declare method inside a method/ constructor or block.
> - Valid only within the block.
> - Created and destroyed within the block.
>
> **Instance/ member variables:**
>
> - Are declared in a class, but outside a method.
> - Also called member or field variable.
> - Is created when an object is created and destroyed when the object is    destroyed.
> - Visible in all methods and constructors of the defining class.
>
> **Class/ static variables:**
>
> - Are declared with the static keyword in a class.
> - Only one copy for class, regardless of how many objects are created from it.
> - Stored in static memory.
>
> And one last thing to keep in mind:
>
> **Variable duration or lifetime of the variable:** The period it exists in the memory before it is destroyed.

To answer your problem: in this `Attack()` you have **local variable**. make it **instance/member variable**.

```
void Attack(String attackerName, String defenderName, double attackerDmg, double defenderHp){
    System.out.println(attackerName + " attacked " + defenderName + " causing " + attackerDmg +  " damage.");
    defenderHp -= attackerDmg;
    System.out.println(defenderName + " now has " + defenderHp + " HP.");
}
```

As I mentioned before: the `double defenderHp` is a parameter. End of the scope it will destroyed. To avoid that you can declare a variable outside the method(instance variable).

As: `double defenderHp;`

Inside the `Attack` method: `this.defenderHp -= attackerDmg;`

You can implement getters and setters. But the roll of this variable is to update value. Because of that, for this reason it is inconvenient(these type of variables called mutators). [learn more about Accessors and Mutators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993236/accessor-and-mutator-in-java) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993236/accessor-and-mutator-in-java).

Comment: Yes. I have realized that too now with the help of the users. Thank you a lot.